# How to successfully draw background JPanel once and update foreground JPanel constantly?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I have a custom JLayeredPane, and I am repainting it in my game loop. There are two custom JPanels added into the JLayeredPane. These are foreground and background JPanels. How do I successfully only draw my background JPanel once, (And repaint when window is re-sized or any other reason) to reduce impact on system resources, while continuing to update my foreground JPanel constantly.

To re-iterate, I dont want to constantly repaint the background JPanel in a loop. I want to repaint it only when it is nessessary, as the background does not change. and is large.

In my attempt to do this, I have only drawn the background once. However. the background JPanel is simply not visible. while the foreground JPanel updates as normal. It is almost as if the foreground JPanel paints ontop of the background JPanel, even though I have both of the JPanels set to `setOpaque(false)`

I have made a mvce which shows my attempt at only drawing the background JPanel once, while updating the foreground JPanel constantly.

The problem with my code is that the background JPanel does not show.

Now. I know that if I were to draw it constantly it would show. But that defeats the purpose of what i'm trying to do. I am trying to only draw it once, and have be seen at the same time

**My code successfully only draws the background JPanel once. The problem is that the background JPanel does not show. How do I fix THIS problem**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JLayeredPane {
    static JFrame frame;
    static Main main;
    static Dimension screenSize;
    public Main() {     
        JPanel backPanel = new BackPanel();
        JPanel frontPanel = new FrontPanel();
        add(backPanel, new Integer(7));
        add(frontPanel, new Integer(8));

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true){
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        frame = new JFrame("Game"); // Just use the constructor

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        main = new Main();
        frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public class BackPanel extends JPanel{
        public boolean drawn = false;
        public BackPanel(){
            setVisible(true);
            setOpaque(false);
            setSize(screenSize);
            JLabel test1 = new JLabel("Test1");
            JLabel test2 = new JLabel("Test2");
            add(test1);
            add(test2);
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawOnce(g);
        }
        public void drawOnce(Graphics g){
            if (!drawn){
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, screenSize.width, 200);
                drawn=true;
            }

        }
    }
    public class FrontPanel extends JPanel{

        public FrontPanel(){
            setVisible(true);
            setOpaque(false);
            setSize(screenSize);
            JLabel test = new JLabel("Test");
            add(test);
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0+screenSize.width/2, 0, screenSize.width/4, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `to increase FPS` Why do you need to increase frame rate? Consider using a javax.swing.Timer to have better control over fps and refresh at a particular frame rate (like 60fps - in other words increasing the fps isn't necessarily advantageous)

Comment: @copeg In my actual project, I attempt to reach the highest FPS possible, and keep updating my game at 60 ticks per second. I have re-worded my answer to say use less system resources instead of to increase FPS.

Comment: The Swing painting system is designed to repaint when necessary - if your painting routine is complex and you wish to do it just once, consider drawing to a BufferedImage the first time, then draw the image to the JPanel

Comment: @copeg I am not sure if you have read my question. I have an issue, where the background JPanel dosent show if I only draw it once. Why would I want to draw the background repeatedly if it dosent change!

Comment: Did read your question - `Why...draw the background repeatedly if it dosent change! ` But it might (this could be the case for window resizing/moves/scrolls/window on top)...this is exactly what a Component does - handles any necessary repaints so you don't have to. Painting shouldn't be resource intensive - if it is consider optimizing or drawing once to an Image which is then drawn.

Comment: @copeg What I would like is for when the background JPanel needs to be repainted, it is. But not constantly in a loop. As that uses unessessary system resources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118255/discussion-between-jammeh-carr-and-copeg).

Answer (score 0):

Try RepaintManager.currentManager(component).markCompletelyClean(component). It will prevent the component from repainting. You might need to do this after each time you add new components.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html#markCompletelyClean%28javax.swing.JComponent%29

Comment: Why would I want to prevent the component from repainting? How would this solve the problem of the back JPanel not being visible when only drawn once, and is behind the front JPanel, being repainted constantly

Comment: I have successfully made it stop repainting! Thats not my problem! My problem is that it dosent show if I repaint it once.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this two lines of code

```
super.paintComponent(g);
drawOnce(g);
```

are the root of problem, I sincerly don't remember how paintComponent works (a test could help) but try to swap them :

```
drawOnce(g);
super.paintComponent(g);
```

maybe, on your original version, you tells JVM to paint the whole component and, only after the AWTEvent has been added to the queue, to draw what you need.
I guess that the awt's documentation will explain it.